# Qt, setRange of QDateTimeAxis cause CPU usage saturation

Tags: qt, cpu-usage

I'm trying to display data according to the time of their acquisition. For this I do something like

```
t = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
points.append(QPointF(t.toMSecsSinceEpoch(),myValue))
```

then to update my X-axis which is a QDateTimeAxis I do

```
axisXtime->setRange(QDateTime::fromMSecsSinceEpoch(points.at(0).x()), QDateTime::fromMSecsSinceEpoch(points.at(points.size()-1).x()));
```

But the latter cause a progressive CPU usage increase until saturation.
Any idea about what I'm doing wrong ?

Thank you

Foufy

Comment: I don't no why but my first line was not include in my post :" Hi everybody I  need some help concerning Qt and DateTimeAxis"

Comment: I'm not familiar with Qt, but progressive CPU usage is usually an infinite loop somewhere. Take smaller steps, i.e break up your last line into the smallest possible steps and verify what they do, before you bring it all together in the `setRange`.

Comment: It's ok, your question is nice and succinct already, no need to edit it back in

Comment: Thank RolfBly. But I've try lot of thing before posting my question. Not understand what's append :(. Will try again with you recommendation.

Answer (score -2):

After lot of tests : no solution. Because I'm more familiar with QCustomPlot I've changed my code using the latter and everything works fine now

see : http://www.qcustomplot.com/index.php/demos/datedemo  for exemple

the most helpful QCustomPlot's command in my case was

```
mCustomPlot->xAxis->rescale();
```

Bye!

Comment: This is a solution anyway ! Why negative votes. Really don'"t' understand this site ;). I take time to propose my own solution!

Comment: It's not a solution to your question *for the next person* who may search and find your question...  ;)